# A possible proof of the Borsuk Ulam theorem without "Homology-Cohomology"

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Assume that $n>1$.

The  configuration space of  $S^n$ is  defined as follows $$M_n=\{(x,y)\in S^n\times S^n\mid x \neq y\}$$

We  have  two  questions:

> 1.Is there a  continuous  function $f:M_n \to S^{n-1}$  with $f(y,x)=-f(x,y)$, for all $x,y \in $S^{n}$?
>
> 2.Is there  a  continuos  function $h: M_n \to \mathbb{R}^n$  such that $h(x,y)=-h(y,x)  $  and $h(x,-x)\neq 0$  for  all  $x,y \in S^n$

If the  answer to  either of these two questions is  "affirmative ", then we can provide an alternative  proof  for  the  Borsuk Ulam theorem, inductively. Because  an  equivalent  formulation of the  Borsuk Ulam theorem is that:

> There is  no  an odd continuous  function $g:S^{n+1}\to S^n$

Assuming that the  answer to either of  the  above two questions is  affirmative, we give a proof  for  the above  equivalent  formulation of the  Borsuk Ulam theorem. The  proof  is  as follows:

Assume  that $g:S^{n+1}\to S^n$ is  an odd continuous  function. then $f(g(x),g(-x))$ ( or  $h(g(x),g(-x))$ ) is  an odd  continuous  function from $S^{n+1}$ to $S^{n-1}$ ( or to $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$). This  obviously  gives  a  contradiction by induction. Because this  situation leads to existence  of  an odd continuous  function from $S^n$ to $S^{n-1}$. Now we apply the induction argument.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Yes  We  want $n>1$ as i wrote  in the  first  line of the  question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose such a function $M_n \to S^{n-1}$ existed. Consider the composition $S^n \to M_n \to S^{n-1}$, where the first map sends $x$ to the pair $(x,-x)$. That composition is an odd continuous function $S^n \to S^{n-1}$, hence can not exist by Borsuk-Ulam.

Comment: @ThomasRot  Yes this was the aim of the question, provided the  answer would be affirmative. But, as the answer shows, it is not the case.

Comment: Sorry i need to stop commenting on my phone